# Get category ID from nav menu

Tags: menus

Recently I am working on wordpress, but I've got stuck in nav menu item issue.
My desireable result was a pull down caption like this: http://www.masterhands.com.tw/index.aspx

- Each category list on nav menu as an item. I made this by a default way: function.php register.
- I am fine with the code of pull down area, it relys on inputing category ID in WP_Query to show most recent 3 posts now. And I seperate it as another php.

But the problems:

- How to get the cat ID but not the menu item ID?
- By just on hover?

I was searching high and low for few days.

This is the way I call post from category (pick category with offset) in a php named : caption.php

```
<div class="content"> 
<?php $cat_id = 2; //the certain category ID
     $latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('offset' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
     if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();  ?>
// Where I post thing...
</div>
```

I tried to dissect it part by part

- caption.php presently included in all php ()
- Hover on "menu li a" trigger pull down (.content is where the container is)

> ```
>  $(document).ready(function(){
> $("#menu-menu-1 a").mouseover(function(){ 
>        $(".content").slideDown(100);
>    });         
> });
> ```

The default menu by wordpress looks like:

```
<div class="menu-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-19">
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/cat2/">cat2</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So I think merely get the cat id from URL while on hover for '$cat_id' is a direct way?

Comment: if you don't show code it is like you haven't asked anything. No telephats around here as far I know :)

Comment: Updated :), Thx for watching the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite complex (both the question and the way to achieve what was asked for).

You would have to set up a new [`Walker`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src//wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L10). In fact, you only need a custom `start_el` function, in which you check if you need/want to build a *pull down area* or not.

You (could) do this with respect to `$item->object_id`. Fetch the post, and check for whatever you like (certain post type, get the category and act upon that, certain date etc.).

The output of the custom query you want to run is then added to the output (either to `$item_output` right before the last line, if you want to have it filtered, or to `$output` after the last line, if you **don't** want to have the output/query filtered).

So, here is a *blueprint* of what I just described (incomplete code!):

```
class MyMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        // ...

        // currently second last line
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        // THIS is where the pull down action is
        $current_post = get_post($item->object_id);
        if (... $current_post ...) {
            $pull_down_query = new WP_Query(array(...args...));
            // add (i.e., concatenate) query output to item output
        }

        // currently last line
        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
    } // function start_el

} // class MyMenuWalker
```

Then, where you are calling `wp_nav_menu`, you add the walker:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    // other args
    'walker' => new MyMenuWalker(),
));
```

The rest is CSS...

I hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thx so much for your suggestion, but it seems quite a different thing to my current set? Or they work togather? Anyway I will study it through. Hope my additional code would help declaring my situation. I am new to wordpress and spending time in try and error. :)

Comment: Are you using `wp_nav_menu` to render your menu? Your current code does not tell. If not, you might want to have a look at [`register_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) and [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). That's where the above `Walker` comes into play.

Comment: I am using the wp_nav_menu to do so. I am looking for something to retrive cat id from its url in menu now. Would that be a right direction?

Comment: Well, then (almost) all you need is right there in my answer. You have to provide a new parameter `'walker'` for your `wp_nav_menu` call. This `Walker` first needs to be set up. This is what I described (and illustrated) in my answer. For each menu element/item you can access the variable/object `$item`, which provides you with a bunch of things. One is the ID of the post that the current menu item links to. So you can fetch the post (using `get_post($item->object_id)`, for instance) and work with that. Or just call [`wp_get_post_categories`] or [`get_the_category`]() or something like that.

Comment: Thx for the inspiraing of walker. I see more from http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/#example-code